# How to detect proper element to show based on the anchor within the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I use a number of Twitter Bootstrap collapse groups on my page. Each group may contain several anchors:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading"> <a href="#section1"></a><a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Section 1</a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <p><a href="#section1-text1"></a>Section 1 - Text 1</p>
                <p><a href="#section1-text2"></a>Section 1 - Text 2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading"> <a href="#section2"></a><a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">Section 2</a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <p><a href="#section2-text1"></a>Section 2 - Text 1</p>
                <p><a href="#section2-text2"></a>Section 2 - Text 2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If my page is opened with particular hash in the URL (like `http://example.com#section2-text2`), then according collapse should shown. I am planning to use `window.location.hash` to understand which collapse to show ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/cf6KH/2/)):

```
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  if (hash == '#collapseOne' || hash == '#collapseTwo') {
    $(hash).collapse('show');
  }
```

But I have two questions:

1. how to identify proper collapse to show if hash doesn't contain it is name (for ex., anchor and hash are `somethingelse-text2`, i.e. doesn't contain `section2`); how to find `parent` collapse element of the anchor `somethingelse-text2`?
2. should I scroll manually to the anchor after collapse showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question you can use something like this:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
if(hash){
    var targetAnchor = $(hash + ",a[href='"+hash+"']");
    if(targetAnchor.length > 0){
        targetAnchor.closest(".collapse").collapse('show');
    }   
}
```

For the second part, browsers usually do this natively, but in your case i'm pretty sure its not going to happen because the anchor is hidden inside your collapse block. If so, you can scroll manually like this:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: targetAnchor.offset().top
}, 2000);
```

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element).

Comment: Thanks, chimmi. The only question I have - first code works well with elements like `#section1-text1`, but doesn't work with elements like `#collapseOne`. Looks like I should identify `targetAnchor` type somehow (`class="accordion-toggle"`?) and either looks for `parent` or apply `collapse('show')` to the element itself.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the code to handle elements like `#collapseOne`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oups, I did the same thing moment later. You'r welcome. One more thing though, keep in mind that some special characters that are allowed in hash may break jQuery selector.